# How do I eliminate space on the right side of a GridView item

Tags: xaml, uwp

So I have struggled with this before but have never found a good solution.

I need a a 2 column GridView with items that will fill into the left and the right with the items on the left being left justified and the items on the right being right justified.  I want the 2 columns to be edge to edge with a space in the middle.  So far I have this but the items don't fill in the container horizontally.  The right margin messes it up.

```
<Grid Background="black" Height="500" Width="200">
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" ItemWidth="100" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 10 0"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <CheckBox Content="Light" Foreground="White" Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White"  />
            <CheckBox Content="Light" Foreground="White" Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White"  />
            <CheckBox Content="Light" Foreground="White" Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White"  />
            <CheckBox Content="Light" Foreground="White" Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White"  />
            <CheckBox Content="Light" Foreground="White" Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White"  />
            <CheckBox Content="Light" Foreground="White" Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White"  />
            <CheckBox Content="Light" Foreground="White" Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White"  />
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

I know there is a css equivalent of only applying a style to odd or even items but I don't think there is similar markup in xaml.  Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you just trying to stretch the width, or is that right side margin of 10 not intentional?

Comment: You set the right margin to 10 here <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 10 0"/>

Comment: On a side note, unless it is mandatory, please do not hardcode width and height of any item in xaml. This will not make the view responsive.

Comment: Chris, the right side margin of 10 is not intentional i would like that to be 0 while still keeping center column and top and bottom spacing.

Comment: AVK Naidu, i know i set that margin, if I set margin to 0 you get no spacing.  I just set the width and height to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: That means, left column should be aligned Left and Right Column to be Aligned Right. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XAML, we can use [**ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleSelector property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector) to apply different styles to odd and even items. This property sets a reference to a custom [**StyleSelector**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.styleselector) logic class. The **StyleSelector** returns different [**Style**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.style) values to use for the item container based on characteristics of the object being displayed. Following is a simple sample about how to do this.

Firstly, we need two styles for odd and even items.

```
<Style x:Key="OddGridViewItemStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 10 0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="EvenGridViewItemStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
</Style>
```

Then we need to create a custom [**StyleSelector**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.styleselector) class and override [**SelectStyleCore method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.styleselector.selectstylecore) to implement the logic. In the method, we can use [**ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemscontrolfromitemcontainer.aspx) to get the **[ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.aspx)** and then use [**ItemsControl.IndexFromContainer method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.indexfromcontainer.aspx) to get the index of the container. Once we have the index, we can use it to check whether the item is odd or even item.

```
public class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style OddStyle { get; set; }
    public Style EvenStyle { get; set; }

    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(container);
        //Note that the index starts form 0
        if (itemsControl.IndexFromContainer(container) % 2 == 0)
        {
            return OddStyle;
        }
        else
        {
            return EvenStyle;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this selector, we need to refer to an instance of the custom class as defined in a [**Resources**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.resources) block in XAML. We can define it in `Page.Resources` like:

```
<local:MyStyleSelector x:Key="MyStyleSelector"
                       EvenStyle="{StaticResource EvenGridViewItemStyle}"
                       OddStyle="{StaticResource OddGridViewItemStyle}" />
```

And in `GridView`, set `ItemContainerStyleSelector` like:

```
<GridView ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource MyStyleSelector}">
```

The complete XAML code might like:

```
<Page ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="OddGridViewItemStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 10 0" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="EvenGridViewItemStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
        </Style>

        <local:MyStyleSelector x:Key="MyStyleSelector" EvenStyle="{StaticResource EvenGridViewItemStyle}" OddStyle="{StaticResource OddGridViewItemStyle}" />

    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid Width="200" Height="500" Background="black">
            <GridView ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource MyStyleSelector}">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="100" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>

                <CheckBox Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White" Content="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <CheckBox Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White" Content="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <CheckBox Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White" Content="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <CheckBox Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White" Content="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <CheckBox Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White" Content="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <CheckBox Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White" Content="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <CheckBox Background="#454545" BorderBrush="White" Content="Light" Foreground="White" />
            </GridView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, I am marking this as the answer as it seems like the right way to do it.  I actually just used a margin of 10,10,10,10 so that it was uniform on all sides.  The only thing that gets me is the way xaml forces you into this much overhead when you want to do such a simple thing.